# issue with TextWacher() for writing unicode(Sindhi) in android

Tags: android

I want to write `unicode` character in `EditText` in this way:

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

        }
        public void  beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){

        }
        public void  onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
            if(s.equals("a")){
                et.append("\u0627");
            }
        } 
    };

    et.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

but this only writes english `chracter`in `EditText`, how to solve this.
thanks in Advance.

Comment: onTextChanged's docs say: "It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback" so probably its not safe to modify EditText as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way may help you

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);


        InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                if(source.toString().equals("a")){
                    return "\u0627";
                }

                return null;

            }
        };

        edt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

**OutPut**

[image]